# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(\sqrt{n})}{n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms

How to determine does this series converge or diverge? I have tried d'Alembert's ratio test but in the limit I get $1$. I suppose I should compare it with some other series, but I can't figure out with which one to compare to.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(\sqrt{n})}{n}$$

Comment: Compare with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It diverges:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(\sqrt{n})}{n} =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n^{\frac{1}{2}})}{n} =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)}{n} =
 \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}\geq
 \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n} =
 \infty$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt n\right)}{n}\ge \frac1n\quad\text{for n large enough}$$

Comment: To me that isn't obvious right away. How could I prove that if I had to use it in a test?

Comment: $\sqrt{n} \rightarrow +\infty$ therefore when you compose by $\ln$ it goes to infinity as well. Alternatively, $ln(\sqrt{n})>1 \Leftrightarrow n > \exp{2}$